# Reference Error in Module Definition - Require JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to get my head around require in simple web applications.  I've got everything working fairly well until I try to execute some code inside a 'define' block;

```js
define(['jquery'], function() {
  var Playlist = function() {
    // bunch of helper code here

  };
  return Playlist;
});
```

If i comment out the define wrapper the code works perfectly, but something I'm doing wrong here is causing 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Playlist is not defined'.

What am I missing about 'define' in AMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
define(['jquery'], function($) {
  var Playlist = function() {
    // bunch of helper code here

  };
  return Playlist;
});
```

And when will you get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: Playlist is not defined` error? Because `Playlist` is in your callback function and you can not use it outside of course.